# Exposed filter does not work in a block

Tags: 7, views

My views shows the nodes of a content type. With an exposed filter I can reduce the result list (e.g. show all entries of a category).

I have a views page and a views block (with same views configuration).

On the page the exposed filter works without problems.
Using the block the exposed filter does not work, no response when I use the exposed filter. The filtering seems to be dead.

Can you help to solve this? Thank you.